# SetActive Random object Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want SetActive 1 index by Random it in Step scripts. And  Count = 2, Random will continue to display, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
public class Step 
{
    public string stepName;
    public GameObject[] objects;
}
```

```
public void AddCount()
    {
        Count++;
        if (Count == 2)
        {
            nextStep();
            Count = 0;
        }
        
    }
    public void nextStep()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < _steps.Count; i++)
        {
            int ranI = Random.Range(0, _steps.Count - 1);

            _steps[ranI].objects[i].SetActive(true);

        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: How is `_steps.count` being set? The `Count` variable in `AddCount` isn’t affecting it.

Comment: I public is  [SerializeField] List<Step> _steps;

Comment: You sure each step holds as many `objects` as there are also steps in `_steps` ...? The access to `_steps[ranI].objects[i]` makes no sense in my eyes ... Sounds like you rather want to pick a random step and then enable all of the according objects..?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that each step holds at least as many objects as there are also steps in the `_steps` list itself...?

The access to

```
_steps[ranI].objects[i]
```

makes no sense in my eyes.

Sounds like what you rather want is to pick a random step and then enable all of the according objects.

In order to also disable the current step I would keep that information and e.g. do

```
// Stores which step is currently being displayed so we can hide it later
private int? currentStepIndex;

public void nextStep()
{
    // if there is currently a step displayed 
    if(currentStepIndex != null)
    {
        // hide all that step's objects
        var step = _steps[currentStepIndex];

        foreach(var obj in step.objects)
        {
            obj.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    // pick a random step
    // Note that the upper index already is exclusive
    // => this will return valid indices between 0 and _steps.Count - 1 now
    currentStepIndex = Random.Range(0, _steps.Count);
    var nextStep = _steps[currentStepIndex];

    // enable all that step's objects
    foreach(var obj in nextStep.objects)
    {
        obj.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

---

personally I would even abstract the loop into the `Step` class itself like

```
public class Step 
{
    public string stepName;
    // This can be private now
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] objects;

    public void SetActive(bool active)
    {
        foreach(var obj in objects)
        {
            obj.SetActive(active);
        }
    }
}
```

and then rather store the `Step` and do

```
private Step currentStep;

public void nextStep()
{
    currentStep?.SetActive(false);

    var currentStepIndex = Random.Range(0, _steps.Count);
    currentStep = _steps[currentStepIndex];

    currentStep.SetActive(true);
}
```

because this way you could also e.g. exclude the current step so you don't randomly pick the same index twice in a row. Or even make sure that every step is only picked once until all steps have been displayed, etc